# VBA Button creates new sheets to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In the code below, I have a button on a user form creating a new sheet from a template, renaming it and opening it in a new workbook as well as the current workbook. Is there anyway to have it automated so it doesn't create the new sheets in the current workbook and just the new workbook? Also it creates a new workbook every time, anyway to get all the new sheets created saved to one workbook when they are created? Anything helps, thanks!

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Employee Information")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Me.cbStores.Value = "Northern / Northmart" Then
Dim newWB as Workbook
Dim thisWB as Workbook
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
set newWB = Application.Workbooks.Add

thisWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
set sh = newWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE")
' Naming and hyperlink to new sheet
sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View"

EndIf
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you rephrase or clarify the problem? For example, this is somewhat ambiguous: *Is there anyway to have it automated so it doesn't create the new sheets in the current workbook and just the new workbook* And so is this: *Also it creates a new workbook every time, anyway to get all the new sheets created saved to one workbook when they are created?*. Please clearly describe what are the expectations, and how the actual output deviates from those expectations.

Comment: Set newWB = Application.Workbooks.Add

Comment: Yeah, you're deliberately creating a *new* workbook each time you run the procedure. What do you actually intend to do, if not this?

Comment: I plan to have all the new sheets created in one workbook that's different from the current workbook I'm using.

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing `For i = 1 to 1`? That's a pointless loop structure.

Comment: I just took that out after re-viewing my code. I had it for something else I disregarded.

Comment: Then you are missing some code... '... all the new sheets...' yet your code only creates ONE sheet.

Comment: Yes I realize that...Its for when I go back into the user form to create another page...For every new sheet that is created.

Comment: And either you need 'Option Explicit' and then compile, or you need to explain why you use 'For i' but then 'Next I' (note they are not the same variable unless you typed in the code you are showing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could tweak your code as follows:

```
    Set newWB = GetOrCreateWB("NewWb", "C:\Users\....\MyFolder") '<--| try getting the already open "NewWb" workbook or opening it from given folder ore create it in given folder

    thisWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(1)
    With ActiveSheet '<--| the just pasted worksheet becomes the active one
        .Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template" '<--| Name it
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
    End With

 Next i
```

which exploites the following funtion:

```
Function GetOrCreateWB(wbName As String, wbPath As String) As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOrCreateWB = Workbooks(wbName)
    If GetOrCreateWB Is Nothing Then
        Set GetOrCreateWB = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & "\" & wbName)
        If GetOrCreateWB Is Nothing Then
            Set GetOrCreateWB = Workbooks.Add
            GetOrCreateWB.SaveAs Filename:=wbPath & "\" & wbName
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Works great, one problem though. The hyperlink is broken. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Well, the _hyperlink_ part was not this question issue while the _only one workbook_ was. You may then want to accept this answer since it solved your _original_ question and then make a _new_ post for the _new_ issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In an ordinary Code Module (not in the UserForm code module), do this *outside of any procedure, at the top of the module*:

```
Public newWB as Workbook
```

Then, your userform code like so (you'll need to modify with your additional code, since I don't have your worksheet structure & data available):

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim thisWB As Workbook
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
If Module1.newWB Is Nothing Then
    Set Module1.newWB = Workbooks.Add
End If

thisWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
Set sh = Module1.newWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE")
' Naming and hyperlink to new sheet
'sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"

'This line raises an error because "ws" is not declared
'ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View"

End Sub
```

The first time you run this code, `Module1.newWB` is nothing, it's not been assigned any object value. So, a new workbook is created using the `Workbooks.Add` method, assigned to the `Module1.newWB` variable, and this variable persists until you close the file or if there is a state loss in the VBA runtime (i.e., an unhandled exception which you abort or terminate runtime, etc.).

Comment: Right, so that's now creating it in a new workbook only which is what I wanted as well, but now I need all the sheets I will be creating from the user form button to go in this new workbook.

Comment: No, you didn't.

Comment: Should be there

Comment: I don't understand how that code is significantly different from the code you initially posted. Have you yet attempted to implement the method I outlined above, in your procedure?

Comment: Yes, the foo procedure creates all the sheets being formed from the button click into different workbooks. However I need all the sheets being formed from the user form button to be placed in just one separate workbook.

Comment: put the code from `foo` (a generic name, since you originall didn't provide the procedure name) in the button's click event handler. Did you try that? It should create all in the same workbook.

Comment: k let me try a few things, might need a little tweak because UserForms work a bit differently.

Comment: Appears to be creating all worksheets in the same workbook UNTIL you close the userform. Reopening the form will create them in *another* new workbook. Is this what you're observing?

Comment: I have the user form automatically closing once hit saved so I'm not to sure.