# Create new workbooks from template sheet and rename them by a given list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template workbook that I need 100s of copies of ("Template"). I have the list of titles of each workbook in Sheet 2 ("Data") of this template workbook.

I've dug around on this site and found this code that does *almost* exactly what I need, except instead of creating a new workbook it creates new sheets within the template workbook.
Is there any change I can make to this to have it generate new workbooks?
Any help is much appreciated, I've never used macros before and anything I tried to change just breaks the code!

The code I found is below:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    With Sheets("Data")
        LastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For a = 1 To LastRow
            Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
            Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            wsNew.Name = Sheets("Data").Cells(a, 1).Value
            wsToCopy.Cells.Copy wsNew.Cells
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! There are numerous threads on StackOverflow about creating new workbooks:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+create+new+workbook This one sounds like it does what you want using a button click: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700091/vba-button-creates-new-sheets-to-new-workbook

Answer (score 0):

### Create Workbooks From Template

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWorkbooksFromTemplate()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const LKP_NAME As String = "Data"
    Const LKP_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Template"
    Const DST_SUBFOLDER As String = "MyNewWorkbooks"
    
    ' Reference the source workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Determine the destination path.
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim dPath As String: dPath = swb.Path & pSep & DST_SUBFOLDER & pSep
    
    ' Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist.
    If Len(Dir(dPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir dPath
    
    ' Write the values from the lookup column to an array.
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = swb.Sheets(LKP_NAME)
    Dim lfCell As Range: Set lfCell = lws.Range(LKP_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim llCell As Range
    Set llCell = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, lfCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range(lfCell, llCell)
    Dim lData(): lData = lrg.Value ' assumes at least two cells
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    ' Copy the source worksheet to a new (single-worksheet) workbook.
    sws.Copy
    
    ' Reference this new workbook, the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    ' Reference the only worksheet in the destination workbook,
    ' the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
    
    Dim lr As Long, dName As String
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the lookup array.
    For lr = 1 To UBound(lData, 1)
        ' Store the current value in the lookup array as a string in a variable.
        dName = CStr(lData(lr, 1))
        ' Check if the cell was not blank.
        If Len(dName) > 0 Then ' cell was not blank
            ' Rename the destination worksheet.
            dws.Name = dName
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
                ' Save the destination workbook using the same name as the name
                ' of the destination worksheet, as a workbook without macros
                ' i.e. with an '.xlsx' extension.
                dwb.SaveAs dPath & dName
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else ' cell was blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next lr
            
    ' Finally, close the destination workbook.
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Workbooks from template created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```